# WebPack - Error can't find .src folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to understand how webpack works, so I create a simple application with `node js` and `react`.

When I run webpack build script I get this error:

`ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'`

I have this folder structure:

```
root
    src
    package.json
    webpack.config
```

`src` contains all application files

and this is my `webpack.config` file:

```
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    devtool: debug ? 'inline-sourcemap' : null,
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app-client.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'public', 'javascripts'),
        publicPath: "/javascripts/",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            loader: ['babel-loader'],
            query: {
                cacheDirectory: 'babel_cache',
                presets: debug ? ['react', 'es2015', 'react-hmre'] : ['react', 'es2015']
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: debug ? [] : [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warnings: false },
            mangle: true,
            sourcemap: false,
            beautify: false,
            dead_code: true
        }),
    ]
};
```

and this is my build script:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check the path in which you are running `webpack`, e.g. if your folder structure is;

Drive
 -> Projects
   -> Project
     -> webpack.config.js

You need to make sure you are running webpack from within the Project folder, otherwise if you are running it outwith, it will load up it's default config file which is defaulted to looking for the `/src` folder.

Comment: I add the script I wrote on this post inside my project, because I set a script named `build` on my `package.json` and then I run it using `yarn build` inside my project